# Page break in PDF sending by batch class

Tags: apex, batch, pdf

I am sending a PDF through batch class. In PDF there are some tables. I want new page every time a new table starts in pdf.

How can I achieve this??

Comment: Does the PDF already exist, or are you hoping to add page breaks to an existing one?

Comment: I have a batch class in which I create the tables in convert in pdf to send it in mail.I need to break page after every table in pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can have a style for tr inside pdf  [see w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp)

```
<style>

{
tr{page-break-after:always;}
}
</style>
```

Comment: I am not usinf visualforce page. I am creating pdf through batch class